# How to add an image to my css body background?

Tags: html, image, css, background

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZP3G.png) is where my image is located.

I already tried several options shown on the picture, I have my css on my html (training purposes ) C:\Users\developer\Desktop\HTML Folder2

Comment: Repost your question in proper format..

Comment: have a read of : https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Place your code here.

Answer (score 0):

the following is taken form https://css-tricks.com

We can do this purely through CSS thanks to the background-size property now in CSS3. We'll use the html element (better than body as it's always at least the height of the browser window). We set a fixed and centered background on it, then adjust it's size using background-size set to the cover keyword.

```css
html { 
  background: url(http://enjoycss.com/webshots/hB_1.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    background: url(HTML Folder2/image.jpg)no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```